# Representing a higher degree polynomial as product of smaller degree polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Consider an equation 
$H(Z)=1+\frac 52Z^{-1}+2Z^{-2}+2Z^{-3}$ 
I want to write it as a product of a first degree polynomial and another polynomial, which will be...$$H(Z)=(1+2Z^{-1})(1+\frac 12Z^{-1}+Z^{-2})$$
My question is **How can we obtain the second form if we are given a polynomial of higher degree**. I have tried making a dummy solution $H(Z)=(a+bZ^{-1})(c+dZ^{-1}+eZ^{-2})$ and tried to find the values of $a,b,c,d$ by equating coefficients of same powers with **equation1** but ended up in big mess.

Comment: Technically, not an equation, just a definition of a function and/or rational expression. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation

Comment: Are you basically asking for a way to factor a polynomial of a high degree? Surely, there is much a lot of literature on that...

Comment: factorize , yes i think that is the correct name

Comment: i need to represent a higher degree polynomial as a product of a first degree polynomial and another polynomial

Comment: it doesn't matter but actually H(z) is transfer function of a digital filter. I need this operation in order to represent it in cascaded form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$H(Z)=a+\frac{b}{Z}+\frac{c}{Z^2}+\frac{d}{Z^3}$$

Then 
$$Z^3H(Z)=aZ^3+bZ^2+cZ+d$$

Now we can use the [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to find the guaranteed real root $\alpha$ of the right hand side  (you can find a derivation of that result [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)).

We can then rewrite the right hand side as

$$aZ^3+bZ^2+cZ+d=(Z-\alpha)\left(aZ^2+(b+a\alpha)Z-\frac{d}{\alpha}\right)$$

This is valid provided $\alpha\ne 0$, but if $\alpha=0$ then $d=0$ and our original expression is already in a reduced form.

Finally we can divide both sides by $Z^3$ again to get the final result:

$$H(Z)=\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{Z}\right)\left(a+\frac{b+a\alpha}{Z}-\frac{d}{\alpha Z^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The short answer for polynomials of higher degree: Sorry, you can't.

What you're asking for is a way to *factor* a polynomial into polynomials of smaller degree.  The fact that you want one of the factors to have degree $1$ means you're looking for a *solution* or *root* of the polynomial, ie a value of $Z$ that makes the polynomial evaluate to $0$.  (Note that finding such a value $a$ is equivalent to finding a degree-$1$ factor, $(Z-a)$).

For a given particular high-degree polynomial, like $Z^{8} - 1$, you may be able to find a way to factor it - in this case, it factors nicely as $(Z^4+1)(Z^2+1)(Z+1)(Z-1)$.

However, for degree $5$ and higher, there is no *general* formula you can apply to always get a root.  This is a famous theorem called the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), which was proved in the early 19th century.

Not only is there no general formula, there are even particular $5^{th}$ degree polynomials, such as $x^5-10x+2$, that don't have solutions you can write down. The study of what polynomials can and can't be factored is called [Galois Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_Theory).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find numerically the factorization of the polynomial into linear and quadratic factors with real coefficients, without resorting to complex numbers, then you can use the [Bairstow algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow%27s_method).

Beware that it only works without instabilities on even degree polynomials. For odd degree polynomials, you first have to find one real root using Newtons method or some secant method (Regula falsi, Illinois method) and deflate the polynomial by one degree using this root.